# When I insert data, it shows '1' in database

Tags: php

I have a strange problem. I'm learning prepared statements. I created a simple page with 1 field `nama` and a table with a column `nama`. I just want to see the data goes in. When I press the submit button, there is data in the table, but everytime I insert data it shows `1`. All the rows display the same figure. Can any one guide me through this?

```
<?php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();

require 'connect-test.php';

$nama= isset($_POST['nama']);

$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (nama) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $nama);
$stmt->execute();
if (!$stmt)
{ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}    

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?> 

<html>
<body>  
<form name="form2" method="post" action="test-deletenanti.php">
  <p>Name :
    <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
  </p>  
</form>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$nama = isset($_POST['nama']);
```

to:

```
$nama = $_POST['nama'];
```

`isset` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the variable is set, so that's what you're putting into `$nama`, instead of the actual value of the input.

You should use `isset()` in an `if` statement around the whole thing:

```
if (isset($_POST['nama'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];

    // rest of code to insert into DB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE
>   otherwise.

Your condition is TRUE and set it to 1

```
$nama= isset($_POST['nama']);
```

Just change to

```
if (isset($_POST['nama'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (nama) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $nama);
        $stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt) {
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
```